# tab dependent sidebars in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny dashboard which has three tabs using `tabBox`, and I would like to use the activated tab to determine/make visible the relevant dashboard sidebar inputs. At the moment they all appear simultaneously...I would like some to disappear according to the tab that is activated.

Below is my current attempt.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

My `ui.R` script is as follows:

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = 'Simple dashbaord'
)
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=12,
           tabBox(
             id='tabvals',
              width=NULL,
              tabPanel('TAB name1',
                       plotOutput('plot1'),value=1),
              tabPanel('TAB name2',
                       plotOutput('plot2'),value=2),
              tabPanel('TAB name3',
                       plotOutput('plot3'),value=3)
            )
     ) 
   )
)


dashboardPage(
   header,
   dashboardSidebar(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input$tabvals == 1",
      sliderInput('slider1','Slider for tab1:',min=1,max=3000,value=30),
      sliderInput('slider2','2nd Slider for tab1:',min=1,max=3000,value=300)
     ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input$tabvals == 2",
      sliderInput('slider3','Slider for tab2:',min=1,max=1000,value=10), 
      sliderInput('slider4','2nd Slider for tab2:',min=1,max=1000,value=500)
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input$tabvals == 3",
      sliderInput('slider5','Slider for tab3:',min=1,max=3000,value=30),
      sliderInput('slider6','2nd Slider for tab3:',min=1,max=3000,value=30)
    )
   ),
  body
)
```

My `server.R` script is as follows:

```
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(input$slider1,input$slider2)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()+
      xlab('X value')+
      ylab('')+
      ggtitle('Distribution of X')+
      theme(
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())

    print(out)
   })
   output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
     out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(input$slider3,input$slider4)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()+
      xlab('X value')+
      ylab('')+
      ggtitle('Distribution of X')+
      theme(
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks = element_blank())

     print(out)
   })
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(input$slider5,input$slider6)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()+
      xlab('X value')+
      ylab('')+
      ggtitle('Distribution of X')+
      theme(
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks = element_blank())

     print(out)
   })


})
```

Comment: try replacing the `$` with a `.` in your `conditonalPanel`'s conditons (`input.tabvals` instead of `input$tabvals`), see `Details` paragraph [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html)

Comment: Thanks! I had just tried that myself...

Answer (score 4):

Changing the conditions from:

```
condition = "input$tabvals == 1",
```

to:

```
condition = "input.tabvals == 1",
```

Helped. Should this be made more consistent across Shiny?